# ASP.Net core custom docker volume mount in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, docker, asp.net-core

Originally I was using [Visual Studio 2017 Tools for Docker](https://github.com/Microsoft/DockerTools) as this was the default in earlier versions of Visual Studio when adding docker support to ASP.NET.

Recently I upgraded to Visual Studio 2017 15.8.0 Preview 2 and I noticed there is a completely new way of doing docker builds using `launchSettings.json`.

The old way had a special `*.dcproj` whos project's SDK attribute pointed to `<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">`.  Inside this project, there was a `docker-compose.yml` and a `docker-compose.override.yml` that pointed to my ASP.Net's `Dockerfile`.  This was very flexible allowed me to do tons of customization like adding a volume mount as follows.

`docker-compose.override.yml:`

```
version: '3.5'
services:
  sample.container:
    volumes:
    - type: bind
      source: C:\config
      target: /config
      read_only: true
      volume:
        nocopy: true
```

This was great as it allowed me to easily point to a config file that was not in the container during debugging.

Now with the new docker tooling in visual studio using `launchSettings.json` and `<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Containers.Tools.Targets" Version="0.2.1686908" />` in the `*.csproj` file the compose files are no longer used, it launches the `Dockerfile` directly.  Below is a copy of my `launchSettings.json`.

I'm really hoping someone can tell me how to add a custom volume mount this new way into the `launchSettings.json` file, see the `Docker` section below.

`launchSettings.json:`

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:55836",
      "sslPort": 44354
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "WebApplication1": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000"
    },
    "Docker": {
      "commandName": "Docker",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "{Scheme}://localhost:{ServicePort}"
    }
  }
}
```

I would also like to say I've been searching for the solution to this problem for several hours now and I've not been able to find any information on the subject.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There are a couple of MSBuild properties that can be used to augment the build/run of a Docker image:

- `DockerfileBuildArguments`: Additional arguments passed to the Docker build command.
- `DockerfileRunArguments`: Additional arguments passed to the Docker run command.

Example:

`<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <DockerfileRunArguments>-v "C:\HostFolder:/ContainerFolder:ro"</DockerfileRunArguments>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>`

Comment: Where can I find a list of all of these properties?  I'm happy to read through .target files if you tell me where they are located or Git repos.

Comment: @AaronStainback Take a loook here. this might be what you are looking for 

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/containers/container-msbuild-properties?view=vs-2017

Comment: @AaronStainback I also found this as well 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/containers/container-launch-settings?view=vs-2017